# Detecting the EnterKey press with _getch() c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to break the loop when enter is pressed so the user inputs a password and then presses enter when finishes it. But it doesn't seem to be working.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<conio.h>
#include <cstring>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::strlen;
#define SIZE 10



int main()
{
    char num[SIZE];
    cout << "Enter a password " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
         num[i] = _getch();

         cout << num[i];
         if (num[i] == '\n') {
             cout << "heey" << endl;
             break;
         }

    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << " it is : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << num[i];
    }
    cout << endl;




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does the `_getc()` function comes from? And does it return a `char` or an `int`, as usually reading functions do?

Comment: This is simply not doable! You can't do that without interfering with your serial console in someway. There is no standard way to "*capture keys*", it's platform specific.

Comment: Look for '\r' instead of '\n'.

Comment: I changed the '\n' to '\r' and it worked. Thank you @user4581301 !!!